# Appium locators don't work with saucelabs Android

Tags: android, appium, saucelabs

I have UI component:

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fire Event"
            android:id="@+id/fireEvent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonViewKruxWebPage"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />
```

And I want to find it using Appium ID locator:
`driver.findElement(By.id("fireEvent"))`. It works fine locally but Appium cannot find it on Saucelabs. Locally and Remotely on Sauselabs both cases I have Appium 1.4.0.
Also i have tried variant of lacator:
`driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.package:id/txtLogin"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long do you wait for element to appear in *findElement* method? It is possible that Saucelabs has bigger delays so I would suggest to increase time-outs and see what happens.